# Generating roll-up with makefile runs even if files don't change

Tags: makefile

I am trying to make a roll-up file of all of the generated css. The `bin/generateTemplates` script handles fetching all the `*.less` files from their nested directories and generating the rollup in `build/gui.css`. However, even if none of the files in `LESS_FILES` changes it still triggers the script to run.

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with the one:many relationship.

```
...

BUILDDIR := build/
LESS_FILES := $(shell find views -type f -name '*.less')
CSS_FILE := build/gui.css

$(CSS_FILE): $(LESS_FILES) $(BUILDDIR)
    bin/generateTemplates

.PHONY: all
all: $(CSS_FILE)

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how it's created or used, but in general you should not list the `$(BUILDDIR)` (or any other directory) as a prerequisite of a target, except in very special circumstances.  The modification time on a directory is updated whenever a file is created, removed, or renamed in that directory, so every time that happens the `$(CSS_FILE)` target is considered out of date, because the directory modification time is newer.